# Tkinter bringing chosen option from optionMenu into a variable for further use

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter.optionmenu

when creating a drop-down menu in "tkinter" like this:

```
options = ['0',
           '1',
           '2',
           '3',
           '4']

option = tk.OptionMenu(menu, var, *options)

var.set('Select number')
```

I want to know exactly how I can take the integer that the user has chosen and turn it into a variable that I can use later on.

Comment: Your question can be answered just by reading available documentation. What part of the problem are you struggling with? It looks like you already know how to associate the widget with a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: how I can take the integer that the user has chosen

You define `options` as a list of `str`, therefore the chosen option are assigned to the given `textvariable`, in your code `var`. To get a `integer` from the `str` do:

```
option_int = int(var.get())
```

---

Working example, how to get the `index` of a chosen `OptionMenu` item:

```
import tkinter as tk

class myOptionMenu(tk.OptionMenu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.item = tk.StringVar()
        self.item.set("Select option")  # default value
        self.index = None
        self.options = ['0. Option', '1. Option', '2. Option', '3. Option']

        super().__init__(parent, self.item, *self.options, command=self.command)
        self.pack()

    def command(self, v):
        # Loop 'options' to find the matching 'item', return the index
        self.index = [i for i, s in enumerate(self.options) if s == self.item.get()][0]
        print("def option({}), variable.get()=>{}, index:{}".format(v, self.item.get(), self.index))
        # >>> def option(2. Option), variable.get()=>2. Option, index:2

root = tk.Tk()

option = myOptionMenu(root)

root.mainloop()
```

> **Usage in the main loop**:
>
> ```
> if option.item.get() == '2. Option':
>     print("Option {} is selected.".format(option.item.get()))
>
> if option.index == 2:
>     print("Option {} is selected.".format(option.index))
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.5.3 - TkVersion: 8.6***